Print some values based on conditions from all json files
I have several json files in a folder and subfolders for which I want to print only 3 fields. I use a for loop over all json files, but here to make it simple, the input below represents 3 json files. For each one, I want to print the "Filename" and "Value" only when inside each file appears at least one "Dmo = Path". When a files doesn´t contain a "Dmo = Path" block, then only print the filename.
{
  "Filename": "File_213",
  "Date": "2024-4-30",
  "Blocks": [
    {
      "Dmo": "WW",
      "Value": "23",
      "String": "",
    },
    {
      "Dmo": "Path",
      "Value": "/Files/2024/abd",
      "String": "",
    },
    {
      "Dmo": "Path",
      "Value": "/Files/2024/Ndew",
      "String": "",
    }
  ]
}

{
  "Filename": "File_4",
  "Date": "2024-4-30",
  "Blocks": [
    {
      "Dmo": "WW",
      "Value": "45",
      "String": "",
    }
  ]
}

{
  "Filename": "File_43",
  "Date": "2024-4-30",
  "Blocks": [
    {
      "Dmo": "Path",
      "Value": "/Files/2023/Roi2",
      "String": "",
    }
    }
  ]
}

My current code and current output is like below
$ awk '/"Filename":/{fnm=$2}
    /Dmo/{dmo=$2}
        /Value/ {

        val=$2;

    if (dmo != "")
        print fnm,val
    else
        print fnm

    fnm=""; dmo="";val=""}' input

"File_213", "23",
 "/Files/2024/abd",
 "/Files/2024/Ndew",
"File_4", "45",
"File_43", "/Files/2023/Roi2",

My expected output is:
File_213, /Files/2024/abd
File_213, /Files/2024/Ndew
File_4
File_43, /Files/2023/Roi2


For structured data, like JSON, you'd be better off using tools that are aware of that structure, like the JSON parser jq. It can process multiple inputs in a single invocation, e.g. with this straight-forward approach:
jq -r '
  if any(.Blocks[]; .Dmo == "Path")
  then .Filename + (.Blocks[] | ", " + select(.Dmo == "Path").Value)
  else .Filename end
' input


.Filename, .Blocks, .Dmo, and .Value access the respective field values, and with [] attached, iterates over the values of that array
any produces true if at least one of the values provided matches a given condition, while select filters its input values according to a given condition
The -r flag decodes the JSON string results into raw texts (essentially, stripping the double quotes)

This produces
File_213, /Files/2024/abd
File_213, /Files/2024/Ndew
File_4
File_43, /Files/2023/Roi2

Demo
As an alternative, one could deduplicate some of the code by transforming the .Blocks array into one with pre-generated result values, and then test for its emptiness using variables for reference:
jq -r '
  [.Blocks[] | ", " + select(.Dmo == "Path").Value] as $a
  | .Filename + if $a == [] then "" else $a[] end
' input

Demo
Another one would be using the // operator to produce an alternative value that is triggered on missing inputs when iterating over that pre-generated array. (This relies on the apparent secondary constraint that all values of .Value are actually strings, i.e. not false or null.)
jq -r '.Filename + (.Blocks | map(", " + select(.Dmo == "Path").Value)[] // "")'

Demo

it works great and concise script. Since my actual case is to process several files in folder and subfolders, how to add the path of the current file processed? it should be outside the jq command? My final goal if to get a "tree" like view of the json files based on the files location and Paths showed in each file.

@Rasec Just replace .Filename with input_filename (no preceding dot!) in any of the examples above to get the path of the currently processed input file. If you want to strip the filename (just retain the path to its containing folder), use string functions to delete everything starting from the last path separator character /, e.g. (input_filename | sub("/[^/]+$"; "")).

I've changed to jq -r 'input_filename + (.Blocks | map(", " + select(.Dmo == "Path").Value)[] // "")' file to process one file and in the output shows the filename without full path like this filename, /Files/2024/abd.  Then, If I run that command inside a for loop, instead of the filename with path I get <stdin>, /Files/2024/abd

@Rasec input_filename produces the name as provided (try jq … dir1/dir2/file), or "<stdin>" if the input comes from STDIN (it was redirected < or piped | into jq rather than a filename arg). Generally speaking, you can probably move the shell loop into jq, so you don't have to redirect/pipe any data (and it'd also be more efficient due to fewer calls from the shell). Alternatively, use jq's --arg option to import a single value (the filename), which you can adopt into the JSON structure to persist as real data, even if the actual file reference is lost due to redirection/piping.

Thanks so much. It works using jq '...' file instead of jq '...' < file

jq is better to process JSON files than awk.
for j in *.json ; do
    jq -r '[.Filename, [.Blocks[] | select(.Dmo=="Path")]] as [$f, $p]
           | if $p[0]
             then ($p[].Value | [$f, .])
             else [$f]
           end | @csv' < "$j" ; done

Output:
"File_213","/Files/2024/abd"
"File_213","/Files/2024/Ndew"
"File_4"
"File_43","/Files/2023/Roi2"


@thanks for your help, it works, I'm trying to adapt it to my actual data but seems to work.
